# What am i doing wrong with this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javascript program that solves the Pythagorean theorem when you give it inputs  . But for some reason its not working. Here is the code: `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script>
       var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
       var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
        function myFunction() {
    var one = Math.pow(a, 2);
    var two = Math.pow(b, 2);
    var xone = (one+two);
    var c = Math.sqrt(xone);
    alert("c="+c);

}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<strong>A</strong>
<input type="text" id="a"></input> <br>
<strong>B</strong>
<input type="text" id="b"></input><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just put the: var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
       var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
inside the function.

Comment: note: `<input>` and `<link>` elements don't admit closing tags

Answer (score 2):

First you need to move your gathering of the data inside of the function.  Otherwise you will never have a value for the inputs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
       //moved two lines below so they are inside the function declaration.
       var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
       var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
    var one = Math.pow(a, 2);
    var two = Math.pow(b, 2);
    var xone = (one+two);
    var c = Math.sqrt(xone);
    alert("c="+c);

}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<strong>A</strong>
<input type="text" id="a"></input> <br>
<strong>B</strong>
<input type="text" id="b"></input><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the script section with the following one:

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var one = Math.pow(a, 2);
    var two = Math.pow(b, 2);
    var xone = (one+two);
    var c = Math.sqrt(xone);
    alert("c="+c);

}
    </script>
```

All you had to do is to move the getElementById lines insied the function :)